# Multiply 2 Values in Assembly Language 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am multiplying two values input from console window. I am using **32 bit registers eax, ebx**, but it is not multiplying the values. The program is running, but it is not multiplying. Can anyone detect the problem?  What is wrong in this code? I am using KIP.R.IRVINE Link Libraries in assembly language.

Here is the code:

```
  INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

  .data

   inputValue1st BYTE "Input the 1st integer = ",0
   inputValue2nd BYTE "Input the 2nd integer = ",0
   outputSumMsg BYTE "The sum of the two integers is = ",0

   num1 DD ?
   num2 DD ?
   sum  DD ?


  .code

  main PROC

   ; here we are calling our Procedures

  call InputValues
  call multiplyValue
  call outputValue
  call Crlf

  exit
  main ENDP



InputValues PROC

;----------- For 1st Value--------
; input message

call Crlf
mov edx,OFFSET inputValue1st
call WriteString


call ReadInt    ; read integer
mov num1, eax   ; store the value


 ;-----------For 2nd Value----------

 ; output the prompt message
 mov edx,OFFSET inputValue2nd
 call WriteString


  call ReadInt  ; read integer
  mov num2, ebx     ; store the value

  ret
  InputValues ENDP



   ;---------multiply----------------

   multiplyValue PROC
   ; compute the sum

    mov eax, num1   ; moves num1 to eax
    mov ebx, num2   ; moves num2 to ebx

    mul ebx  ; num1 * num2 = 6 * 2
    mov sum, eax  ; the val is stored in ebx


    ret
    multiplyValue ENDP


    ;--------For Sum Output Result----------

    outputValue PROC


    ; output result
    mov edx, OFFSET outputSumMsg
    call WriteString


    mov eax, sum
    call WriteInt ; prints the value in eax
    ret
    outputValue ENDP


    End main
```

One more question: Do I need to use a carry flag in it?  If so, then what would the code for it look like?

Comment: the comment ; num1 * num2 = 6 * 2 in multiply PROC is a example

Comment: You're expecting the second `ReadInt` call to return the value in `ebx`. My guess is that the return value actually is located in `eax`.

Comment: Ye Alexey Frunze... I am compiling/ debugging in Visual Studio 2010 and using KIP.R.IRVINE Link Library for assembly language.. THe PROGRAM is working but it is not Multiplying the values...

Comment: Michael...ReadInt takes value in eax...but if i take 2 values in eax (ReadInt) then it OVERRIDES the second value in first..it prints me back the second value if i take 2 values in eax..if i take 1st value in eax and second ebx then also it is not multiplying..for example if i multiply 5 * 2 it returns me +2146787328 ..so how i multiply the values i have read alot about multiplying..but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

```
;mov eax, num1   ; moves num1 to eax
;mov ebx, num2  ; moves num2 to ebx
```

Might just help a little if you were to actually load the values into the registers rather than comment that this is what you should be doing,

Comment: its by mistakenly done by me when i was posting the question if i comment out these instruction    mov eax, num1   ; moves num1 to eax
                                 mov ebx, num2                               then also it is not working

Comment: if i remove the comment then also it is not working sorry for inconvenience...i have written it by mistakenly..

Answer (score 0):

you have error when you input second value ReadInt always puts the values in eax but you say:

```
call ReadInt  ; read integer
mov num2, ebx     ; store the value
```

it must be

```
call ReadInt  ; read integer
mov num2, eax     ; store the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)

```
TITLE MultiplyTwoNumbers (multiply.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

inputValue1st BYTE "Input the 1st integer = ",0
inputValue2nd BYTE "Input the 2nd integer = ",0
outputSumMsg BYTE "The sum of the two integers is = ",0

num1 DD ?
num2 DD ?
sum  DD ?


.code

main PROC

; here we are calling our Procedures

call InputValues
call multiplyValue
call outputValue
call Crlf

exit
main ENDP



InputValues PROC

;----------- For 1st Value--------
; input message

mov edx,OFFSET inputValue1st
call WriteString


call ReadInt    ; read integer
mov num1, eax   ; store the value


 ;-----------For 2nd Value----------

 ; output the prompt message
 mov edx,OFFSET inputValue2nd
 call WriteString


  call ReadInt  ; read integer
  mov num2, eax     ; store the value

  mov eax,0

  ret
  InputValues ENDP



   ;---------multiply----------------

   multiplyValue PROC
   ; compute the sum

    mov eax, num1   ; moves num1 to eax
    imul eax, num2   ; multiplies content in eax with num2 
    mov sum, eax  ; the val is stored in eax


    ret
    multiplyValue ENDP


    ;--------For Sum Output Result----------

    outputValue PROC


    ; output result
    mov edx, OFFSET outputSumMsg
    call WriteString


    mov eax, sum
    call WriteInt ; prints the value in eax
    ret
    outputValue ENDP


    End main
```